# iOS -- multiply the R, G, B, and A components of a UIImage object by constants?

Tags: iphone, image, ios, image-processing, uiimage

Given a UIImage object, I want to programmatically multiply the R, G, B, and A components of its colors by fixed constants.  So, for instance, if I choose 1,0,0,1 for my constants, I would basically grab the red component of the image, while discarding the rest.

Is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some quick searching brought up this tutorial:

http://brandontreb.com/image-manipulation-retrieving-and-updating-pixel-values-for-a-uiimage/

From what I can see, that tutorial involves drawing the UIImage onto a buffer in memory, manipulating that buffer, then transferring the pixel data from that back to the UIImage.

Basically, there's no *simple* way to do that with any of the methods of UIImage.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer.  It works, though I am still trying to figure out how to adapt it for the existence of both retina and non-retina devices.  The bitmap functions appear to behave differently in the two cases, resulting in it doubling the scale of my images on a retina, and failing altogether on a non-retina.  Still, it's a great start.